# How to disable cache for a Storage in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to disable the cache for specific Storage in Sencha Touch?

Do you know any way to disable the cache for all Storages in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which cache are you referring to? If it's the browser cache (for example, when using an [ajax proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-noCache)) then that should be on by default (it uses a separate query param in each request, `_dc` by default). If you mean model records being stored in memory, you may want to look at the [`useCache` config option](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-useCache) of the `Model`.

Comment: I was interested in the in memory representation of the store. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sure thing, glad it helped - and keep those reference docs open, they're probably the best help I've had (other than here).

Comment: Thanks for your advice and support!